# Cannot get VPN connection to work - AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I bought a VPN account and I'm trying to connect to it following instructions given by the vpn Provider (RA4W). I'm using ubuntu 16.4 Basically I'm instructed to install openVPN and then config and connect by entering:

```
sudo openvpn --config path/to/location.ovpn
```

Which results in:

```
$ sudo openvpn --config ~/Desktop/ra4wvpn-nl-amsterdam-udp-1194.ovpn
Fri Sep  1 13:45:15 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL 
(OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Fri Sep  1 13:45:15 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, 
LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: ******
Enter Auth Password: **********
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification 
method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for 
more info.
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth 
using INLINE static key file
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992-
>212992]
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 UDPv4 link remote: 
[AF_INET]154.59.112.130:1194
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 TLS: Initial packet from 
[AF_INET]154.59.112.130:1194, sid=9c75530e 3e238e30
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 WARNING: this configuration may cache 
passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=RA4WVPN
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=RA4WVPN
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message 
hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message 
hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Fri Sep  1 13:45:26 2017 [RA4WVPN] Peer Connection Initiated with 
[AF_INET]154.59.112.130:1194
Fri Sep  1 13:45:28 2017 SENT CONTROL [RA4WVPN]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' 
(status=1)
Fri Sep  1 13:45:28 2017 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
Fri Sep  1 13:45:28 2017 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process 
exiting
```

I tried using the Network Manager as well, but it fails to connect as well and tells me:

```
VPN Connection Failed
The VPN connection 'ra4wvpn-nl-amsterdam-udp-1194' failed because the connection attempt timed out.
```

I am lost as I have no idea what I can try to make it work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but ... I connect to a VPN for a customer, I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I installed network-manager-vpnc, network-manager-pptp and network-manager-openvpn. (I probably only need network-manager-openvpn but installed them all anyway) I could then use the network manager GUI to connect to the VPN. I needed to get the user credentials from my customer, but it all just worked. I guess the credentials you need are in the file "ra4wvpn-nl-amsterdam-udp-1194.ovpn", have you opened it in a text editor to see.

Comment: "auth-failure" indicates you use the wrong credentials.

Comment: I was using the wrong credentials indeed (I had not noticed that I needed to login with my account username and password to get a different VPN username and password)
Works now, Thank you both!

Answer (score 7):

Solved.

As suggested in [a comment by Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951904/cannot-get-vpn-connection-to-work-auth-received-control-message-auth-failed/951943#comment1516556_951904), this message indicated the problem:

```
AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
```

I was simply using the wrong credentials (I had not noticed that I needed to login with my account username and password to get a different VPN username and password).

Comment: Where did you find the username/password?  I have been digging through the site and can't find it at all

Comment: I feel like an idiot. THANK YOU. I am glad we are a tribe of idiots. lololol. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In case you find yourself in my same situation: I was trying to connect a **Synology** to **ProtonVPN**.

After endless try I found out I had to use the as user/password the `IKEv2 user/password`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I fixed it simply by adding firewall rule on ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

First add openvpn UDP port 
copy and paste the command below

`sudo ufw allow 1194/udp`

and then try it again.